# Ubuntu deb installation error

Tags: ubuntu, deb

I'm trying to install a deb file ywe-wdk from http://connectedtv.yahoo.com/developer/ (Yahoo TV SDK)

I double clicked on the deb file but I'm getting this error message:
Error: Wrong architecture "i386"

I read "sudo dpkg --force-architecture -i debname.deb".
Would that command be safe or would it be recommended?
What other options can I take if it's not recommended?

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to fit a ball in a slot meant for a cube. If dpkg alerts you about wrong processor architecture, then it probably IS wrong.

What does `uname -a` return you? And is the dpkg meant for i386 or x86_64/amd64 architecture?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on a 32 bit version and the deb file you are trying to install is 64 bit